# Porque a função crosstab não funciona no laravel? Usando PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-5

Montei uma query que possui um crosstab, no gerenciador da base de dados funciona perfeitamente e não dá nenhum erro, porém quando vou executar essa query dentro do meu projeto que é em laravel, ele explode um erro dizendo que a função não existe.

**> Erro: SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERRO: função crosstab(unknown) não existe**

Já tentei executar o comando abaixo:

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```

Mas fala que já existe a função.

Minha base de dados é PostgreSQL, e meu projeto está em Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Eu mesmo consegui resolver galera!

Apenas coloque o nome da schema antes da função 'crosstab', e se caso não funcionar coloque o public antes da função, porque pode ser que as função da base de dados podem estar configuradas publicamente e não para cada schema. caso nenhum funcione rode o comando abaixo que tudo funcionará perfeitamente.

```
CREATE EXTENSION tablefunc;
```